# How to calculate the characteristic function of compound Poisson random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $\phi_X(t)$ be the characteristic function of $X$. Let $N$ be a Poisson random varivale with mean $1$ and $(X_i)_{\in\mathbb{N}}$ be i.i.d. copies of $X$. Then how to derive the charactersitics function of $S=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$.

My attempts: $\phi_S(t)=E(e^{it\sum_{i=1}^NX_i}).$ How to continue?

Comment: Choosing the index $i$ to enumerate the random variables when one considers characteristic functions involving $i$ the complex number is a bit perverse, no?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use that $(X_i)_i$ and $N$ are independent:

$$\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, t S} = \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{n \geq 0} e^{\imath \, t \sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j} 1_{\{N=n\}} \right) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \mathbb{E} \left(e^{\imath \, t \sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j} \right) \cdot \mathbb{P}(N=n).$$

> **Solution:** $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, tS} &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \underbrace{\phi_X(t)^n}_{\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, t \sum_{j=1}^n X_j}} \cdot \underbrace{e^{-1} \frac{1}{n!}}_{\mathbb{P}(N=n)}= e^{\phi_X(t)-1}. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Why is it true that $e^{itZ_N} = e^{itZ_N} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} I_{\{N=n\}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{itZ_n}  I_{\{N=n\}}$? Is this the same as conditioning on $N$?

Comment: @user398843 No, that's just a pointwise identity: $$1 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1_{\{N=n\}}(\omega).$$ Note that the sets $\{N=n\}$ are pairwise disjoint and cover $\Omega$, i.e. $\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \{N=n\}=\Omega$.